# How to enable company registration on Magento CE?

Tags: magento-1.9, register

My customer registration form only shows simple user related fields. ( First name, Last name, etc. ) I even checked the 'is_required' field in DB in eva_attr. table on the Company row but still nothing.

It really annoys me and I can't make it work... I tried amending the xml templates but it won't do anything.

How do I show the company field on the registration form???

Please help, it's killin me.... :@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DanielDioszegi,company is ***an address type field of customer entity***.If you want to **`enable this field at customer registration`** then  you should enable all customer address field sat registration form by change code at layout xml file

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setData"><key>show_address_fields</key><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

**or** ,change at  *app/design/frontend/Your_package/Your_Template/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml*

**from** `<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>`

**to** `<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>`